# BeagleBone USB network is uncreachable

Tags: embedded-linux, beagleboneblack, kura

I am trying to make my Beaglebone run Eclipse Kura,I connect to its SSH server just like I always do,İnstalled Kura,then I reboot and try to connect with SSH again

```
ssh: connect to host 192.168.7.2 port 22: Network is unreachable
```

I get this error every time I try to connect my Beaglebone's SSH server.
How can I connect again ?
`

Answer (score 0):

Kura should not be blocking any SSH ports. Can you confirm the IP address of the BB didn't change? Maybe connect the BB to a monitor to verify its network settings.